# Datastage. How to manage output of lookup stage?

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, datastage

I have two source files File A and File B, i have to use 3 different lookup stages for 3 different conditions those conditions are deriving new column each in each lookup used, i want those new derived columns in my final output with other columns present in the input file. How i can do that?
Can anybody suggest some solution.

Answer (score 1):

Given the understanding of two files could be combined in one output, use merge for File A and File B, then go on with each look up to take and carry the output along with other source columns. This approach will provide you the presence of all the input columns in addition to the columns arrived from your lookup's.

Answer (score 0):

So, File A has fields X, Y.

File B has fields X, A, B, C.

You want the output file to only have A, B, C?

That's super easy if you're using Datastage PX. Just use a modify stage right before your output and drop the fields you don't want.

A benefit of modify stage is that it doesn't compile down into an actual PX operator - it just attaches itself as a modification to the input of the next stage. It was never an operator in the original Torrent/APT code.